# How can I avoid to line-through my delete X in my TO - Do app in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to code a to-do app in JavaScript, using HTML and CSS. My issue is that when I apply the text-decoration: line-through property to the list elements, it also affects the X icon (which is used to delete tasks). I believe the problem lies in the fact that the icon is a child of the li element, but I'm unsure of how to prevent this behavior.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To Do App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-..." crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="content">
        <h1 class="title">Things To-Do</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <input type="text" id="input" class="input" placeholder="Write the task you want to complete...">
            <button class="btn" onclick="addTask()">ADD</button>
        </div>
        <ul class="task-container" id="task-container">
            <!-- Tasks go here -->
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

My CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 70%;
    height: 80vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    background: white;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px #aaaaaa;
}

.title {
    width: 70%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
    background: white;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 80%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: white;
}


.input {
    min-width: 250px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.btn {
    width: 15%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}



.task-container {
    width: 80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1rem;
}

.task {
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 28px;
    background: rgb(248, 248, 248);
    border-radius: 5px;
    list-style: none;
}

.icon {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.checked {
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

/* Missing some media queries to be added. */
```

And my JS:

```
// Constants
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const taskContainer = document.querySelector(".task-container");

// Function used to create new tastk
function addTask() {
    // If the user don't write anything, show an error
    if (input.value === '') {
        alert("You must write something!");
    } else {
        let li = document.createElement("li");          // Create a new list element
        li.innerHTML = input.value;                     // Copy the text on the input
        li.classList.add("task");                       // Give the task a class
        taskContainer.appendChild(li);                  // Append element to the task container
        let icon = document.createElement("i");         // Create a new icon
        icon.classList.add("icon", "fa-solid", "fa-x"); // Give the icon some classes
        li.appendChild(icon);                           // Append icon to the list 
    }
    input.value = ""; // Empty the input
}

//Event listener for list
taskContainer.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === "LI") { 
        e.target.classList.toggle("checked");
    }
}, false);

// Event listener for icon
taskContainer.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === "I") { 
        e.target.parentElement.remove();
    }
}, false);
```

I tried to append the element to the task-container, but it didn't work as expected because I'm unsure how to select the correct list element for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Update the JS code:

```
function addTask() {
    // If the user don't write anything, show an error
    if (input.value === '') {
        alert("You must write something!");
    } else {
        let li = document.createElement("li");          // Create a new list element

        // Create a span for task text
        let taskText = document.createElement("span");
        taskText.innerHTML = input.value;
        taskText.classList.add("task-text");

        // Create a delete icon
        let icon = document.createElement("i");
        icon.classList.add("icon", "fa-solid", "fa-x"); // Give the icon some classes

        // Append task text and delete icon to the list
        li.appendChild(taskText);
        li.appendChild(icon);

        li.classList.add("task");                       // Give the task a class
        taskContainer.appendChild(li);                  // Append element to the task container
    }
    input.value = ""; // Empty the input
}
```

In the CSS:

```
/* Add a class for styling the task text with line-through */
.task-text {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.checked .task-text {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to delete the class ".task-text" inside the ".checked .task-text" on the css to make it work, but your solution works! Thank you!!

Comment: It's my pleasure, happy hacking!